# How to make a closed component labeling for large structures in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I know how to make a closed component labeling for small structures with the help of `bwlabel`. However, I have now the following image:

[image]

And using bwlabel on this image results only in two classes, the edge - and the everything around it.

I was wondering if there is an easy solutin in matlab to get the inner part of the "circle" as one class and the outer one as another class? The border could be a third class.

The code I have so far is onyl for testing bwlabel

```
i = imread('apple.jpg')
labels = bwlabel(i)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@Shai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49511627/1714410) should be faster and easier

---

Easy: just make labels twice, once filling.

```
% load
I=rgb2gray(imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnJUn.png'));
I=I(:,1:end-2); %some artifacts in the corners of the SO image

labels = bwlabel(I);
filled=imfill(I,'holes'); % fill
labels2= bwlabel(filled);
labels=labels+labels2;
```

[image]

Comment: why running `bwlabel` twice if you can change the connectivity from 8-connect to 4-connect?

Comment: @Shai there is an inverse L shaped corner in the bottom left.

Comment: I don't have access to Matlab at the moment, but AFAIK this "L" shape should not bother the 4-connect

Comment: @Shai ah, true. It is the inverse of what the problem would be! My bad.

Answer (score 4):

Matlab's [`bwlabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) uses [8-connect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_connectivity) connectivity to connect neighboring pixels. Since your boundary is very thin, the diagonal connections connect inner and outer pixel resulting with a single label.
However, if you use 4-connect connectivity

```
 labels = bwlabel(~i, 4);
```

You should get you desired output.

---

BTW,
It is best [not to use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14790740/1714410).

Comment: This would label each of the 4-connected strokes in the circle as separate regions, but the inner part of the circle and the area outside it would still be labeled as background, forming a single component. If you invert the image you'd get the correct effect: `bwlabel(~i,4)`.